# Kyu 8 Code Wars - Finding the Sum of an array after removing the highest and lowest values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am practising on code wars and am currently stuck on a kyu 8 question, all the tests seem to pass bar the last one. I will add my code and the tests below plus the output I get below.

```js
function sumArray(array) {

  if (array == null || array.length <= 2) {
    return 0
  } else {

    let largestInt = Math.max.apply(null, array)
    let smallestInt = Math.min.apply(null, array)
    let indexSmallest = array.indexOf(largestInt)
    let indexLargest = array.indexOf(smallestInt)

    array.splice(indexSmallest, 1)
    array.splice(indexLargest, 1)

    let sum = 0

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      sum += array[I]
    }

    return sum

  }
}
```

---

The tests:

```
const {
  assert
} = require("chai");

it("example tests", () => {
  assert.strictEqual(sumArray(null), 0);
  assert.strictEqual(sumArray([]), 0);
  assert.strictEqual(sumArray([3]), 0);
  assert.strictEqual(sumArray([3, 5]), 0);
  assert.strictEqual(sumArray([6, 2, 1, 8, 10]), 16);
  assert.strictEqual(sumArray([0, 1, 6, 10, 10]), 17);
  assert.strictEqual(sumArray([-6, -20, -1, -10, -12]), -28);
  assert.strictEqual(sumArray([-6, 20, -1, 10, -13]), 3);
});
```

The output:

Test Results:
example tests
expected -10 to equal 3

Comment: When you use array.splice, afterwards the array becomes shorter, and the indices are different.  So `indexLargest` may no longer be correct.  I suggest you find indexSmallest, splice it, find indexLargest, splice it.

Comment: @BiggyJ_Dev ... Regarding the so far provided sole answer / approach are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function total(array) {
  // always assure at least an empty array.
  array = Array.from(array ?? []);

  // sort array values ascending.
  array.sort((a, b) => a - b);

  array.pop();    // remove last/higest value.
  array.shift();  // remove first/lowest value.

  // for any to be reduced/summed-up (empty) array
  // the initial value of zero always assures the
  // minimum expected result of zero.
  return array
    .reduce((total, value) => total + value, 0);
}

const testEntries = [
  [ null, 0 ],
  [ [ ], 0 ],
  [ [ 3 ], 0 ],
  [ [ 3, 5 ], 0 ],
  [ [ 6, 2, 1, 8, 10 ], 16 ],
  [ [ 0, 1, 6, 10, 10 ], 17 ],
  [ [ -6, -20, -1, -10, -12 ], -28 ],
  [ [ -6, 20, -1, 10, -13 ], 3 ],
];
console.log(
  testEntries
    .map(([value, result]) =>
      `(total([${ value }]) === ${ result }) ... ${ total(value) === result }`
    )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```